# How to retrieve a list of databases on a specified server in C#?

Tags: c#, database

I have two combo boxes in my form app. 
When the form loads I do this:

```
combobox1.items.add(system.environment.machinename).
```

Thats works. Now i want to populate the second combo box with the databases of the selected server. How do I do that?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ????????
}
```

Comment: **WHAT** database!?!!? There is no unified, globally valid way of doing this - every database has a bit different ways of achieving this. So we definitely need to know **what** database (and which version) you're using!

Answer (score 1):

Try

in .NET you can use the [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("localhost");
foreach (Database db in server.Databases) {
    Console.WriteLine(db.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can have database with following query:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
```

You can execute procedure `sp_databases` too:

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

Comment: The OP has the server name, but he needs to find the instances on that server - your SQL won't help with that.